# Views math expression or Computed field to find date difference in views

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have two content type, Bill (Type1) and Cash Receipts (Type2), Type2 referencing Type1 when cash is received.

In Type1 I have date field called (Bill Issue date), and Type2 I have date field cash receipt date.

So I want to calculate, different between those two dates. I was trying by creating views with two date (by entity reference relationship), then subtract two filed with math expression field, but it return zero.

Actually, I have no idea whether I was wrong or Its not possible to calculate different between dates with views math expression field?

I think, it can be done with Computed Field, I did one within same content type, but I don’t know how to access a field from different content type, please help.

Code that I was used to calculate date for same content type, but how I can access a field from other content type?

If the Machine name of your date-field is 'field_example_date', then the Computed Code (PHP) would be

```
$startdate = $entity->field_example_date['und'][0]['value']; // Value of start-date
$enddate = $entity->field_example_date['und'][0]['value2']; // Value of end-date

$datediff = strtotime($enddate) - strtotime($startdate);
/* The PHP Function STRTOTIME parses the english textual datetime description
 * into a Unix timestamp
 */

$num_leaves = $datediff/(60*60*24);
/* Since we need the number of days IN-BETWEEN, 
 * we divide the resultant difference by 60*60*24 . 
 *
 * Incase of counting no.of days "FROM" to "TO" days, add 1 to the above result.
 * $num_leaves = $datediff/(60*60*24) + 1;
 */

 $entity_field[0]['value'] = $num_leaves;





The Display Code (PHP) will have

$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this use a template file, since you can use PHP inside templates in Drupal 7

In your view

[image]

Now, add both of your date fields and do this to each of them

[image]

In your web directory, go to **/sites/all/themes/[yourtheme]/templates** folder

Create a file named views-view-fields--**[view-name]**--**[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbNIb.jpg)**.tpl.php

EX: `views-view-fields--hello-world--block-1.tpl.php`

Inside the template file put:

```
<?php

$date1 = new DateTime('$fields["field_invoice_issue_date"]->content');
$date2 = new DateTime('$fields["field_payment_receipt_date"]->content');
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days "; 

// shows the total amount of days (not divided into years, months and days like above)
echo "difference " . $interval->days . " days ";

?>
```

Remember to flush/clear the cache to see changes.

Comment: I was trying to follow your each step, but no success.  Its table format, my views name is "date_calculator" and its page view, so I added code into views-view-fields--date_calculator--page.tpl.php on the other hand there no option to add custom date format in view so I added your format from admin/config/regional/date-time and then select it. Filed name is field_invoice_issue_date and field_payment_receipt_date . So what I need to do?

Comment: `I added code into views-view-fields--date_calculator--page.tpl.php` your view name needs to be **views-view-fields--date-calculator--page.tpl.php** I have added your date fields to the code.

Comment: I have updated the code, I noticed I had a minor error.